# Find a solution for 23x=5 (mod 60)

Tags: euclidean-algorithm

The topic is euclidean algorithm and GCD. This is a simple question, but I'm just stuck finding an inverse for 23 in $Z_{60}$.

I performed the algorithm and proved that 23 and 60 are coprime, so there *is* a single inverse.

Answer (score 0):

We perform the Extended Euclidean Algorithm:

\begin{align}
60 &= 2 \cdot 23 + 14 \\
23 &= 1 \cdot 14 + 9 \\
14 &= 1 \cdot 9 + 5 \\
9 &= 1 \cdot 5 + 4 \\
5 &= 1 \cdot 4 + 1 
\end{align}

Working backwards, we can write
\begin{align}
1 &= 5 - 1 \cdot 4 \\ 
&= 5 - (9 - 1 \cdot 5) \\
&= 2 \cdot 5 - 1 \cdot 9 \\
&= 2 \cdot (14-1 \cdot 9) - 1 \cdot 9 \\
&= 2 \cdot 14 - 3 \cdot 9\\
&= 2 \cdot 14 - 3 \cdot (23 - 1 \cdot 14) \\
&= 5 \cdot 14 - 3 \cdot 23 \\ 
&= 5 \cdot (60 - 2 \cdot 23) - 3 \cdot 23 \\
&= 5 \cdot 60 - 13 \cdot 23.
\end{align}

Looking at $1 = 5 \cdot 60 - 13 \cdot 23$ we find
\begin{align}
-13 \cdot 23 \equiv 47 \cdot 23 \equiv 1 \mod 60.
\end{align}

Multiplying with $5$:
\begin{align}
23 \cdot 47 \cdot 5 \equiv 5 \mod 60
\end{align}

So the solution $\overline{x}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{60}$ is given by

\begin{align}
\overline{x} = \overline{47 \cdot 5} = \overline{55}.
\end{align}